# How do I have to understand the Response measurement of optomechanical coupling with a network analyzer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, quantum-measurements

I have a optomechanical device like a beam which couples to a membrane. My procedure is to lock my laser frequency near the optical resonance. Why should always the steepest point be chosen? I now take network analyzer and want to measure with it the response of beam and membrane. I set an excitation. The network analyzer outputs a voltage V(t), this activates the piezo and the piezo is deflected with du/dV, thereby a force F(t) is exerted on the beam, which is then displaced with u(t). The displacement now results in an amplitude A(t). Have I forgotten anything else? Now the whole coupling. The mechanical vibration with displacement u(t) translates into a periodic change in cavity length, thus shifting the optical resonant frequency and periodically modulating the amplitude of the cavity field. Thus, the photocurrent I obtain is equal to the mechanical frequency and its amplitude A(t) is proportional to the displacement x and the linearized coupling strength G. Is this correct? Am I missing something, because I would get an amplitude with the units 1/Hz, which I think is not correct. From voltage out and voltage in you get your Respone.
Is this the correct measurement procedure?